# RTS5249 Card Reader not working

Tags: drivers, sd-card

My card reader is not working:

```
$ lspci 
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please accept the answer below if it solved your problem (click the checkmark on the left). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to this http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=124956 you should add `rtsx_usb` to `/etc/modules`.